# service not singleton inside MatDialog module

Tags: angular, angular5

When I open a Mat Dialog popup ( angular material ) and accessing a singleton service, for some reason inside the mat dialog the service seems to be a new instance of the service and not the singleton service used across the app.

I know how to make workaround but I prefer understanding if there is a known issue with matdialog and maybe a fix.

```
  const dialogRef = this.dialog.open(MyComponent, {
  width: '400px',
  data: {
    myInfo: Info
  },
});
```

The service was added in the "App.component.ts" as a singleton like this:

```
import {Component, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import {NavigationEnd, Router} from '@angular/router';
import {AuthService} from './shared/services/auth.service';
@Component({  selector: 'app-root',  templateUrl: './app.component.html',  styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss'],  

providers: [AuthService]})    export class AppComponent implements OnInit {}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, the problem is that you are declaring `service` inside `AppComponent`, but `material dialogs` are spawning outside your `app-root` (`angular cdk` is spawning as last element in `body`) so it's not available for your `dialog component`. To fix this you should declare provider `AuthSerivce` inside your main `AppModule` then it will be visible in your dialog component.

Comment: The AuthService already exists in the AppModule and before it was added to the app compontent it wasn't singleton at all.
the service is available in the dialog but as a new instance which is a problem..